# Facebook URL Scheme does not work fb://publish

Tags: android, iphone, ios, facebook, url-scheme

I just realized that the Facebook URI scheme publish function does not work anymore. It opens the Facebook app, but nothing more. Is there any way to publish something via an URI scheme?
You can find my code below.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://publish/profile/me?text=foo"];        
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]];
```

Comment: This doesn't work on Android anymore either, so I added a bounty if someone knows how to do it now. It should work from a website too (this is why it should be done with an URI scheme instead of the Facebook SDK...)

Comment: fb://publish/?text=some text to post or fb://publish/profile/{fbid}?text={message}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is how it can be done with URLs:

[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/)

You need an access token from facebook. After that you can follow this link descriptions and requirements.

[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

And there is a Graph API explorer for HTTP requests.

[link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552_10150189643478553)

I hope this will be helpful for you. In my case, I use iOS Social Framework which is easy to use and user friendly.

Answer (score -1):

There was an SDK update some time back that change how the URL scheme works.  You might want to make sure you have it setup correctly if you have recently updated an old SDK.

The new way to do this is described in the Facebook Developer portal here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/

Specifically, drill down to step 5 and take a look at the last screen shot in the section.

You can clearly see that the URL scheme now must include your Facebook app ID.

Comment: I'm not sure, but as I understood, this URI scheme `fbAPPID:` is only for callbacks of the Facebook App to the custom iOS app (That's why the App ID is in the URI scheme)... Mostly for OAuth...

Comment: you are correct.  I misunderstood OPs question in my initial read.

Answer (score -2):

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://profile/me?text=foo"];        
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]];
```